# Cant use variable from a function in another function

Tags: function, powershell, variables, parameter-passing

```
function User-Search($input)
{
    Write-Host "Searching for user: $input"
    pause
}


function Show-Menu
{
     param (
           [string]$Title = 'MainMenu'
     )
     cls
     Write-Host "================ $Title ================"
     Write-Host " "
     Write-Host "Specify computer / username"
     Write-Host " "
     Write-Host "Q: Press 'Q' to quit."
     Write-Host " "
}

do
{
    Show-Menu
    $input = Read-Host "Search"
    User-Search -input $input
}
until ($input -eq 'q')
```

Outputs: "Searching for user:", it's empty.

There must be some small mistake i am doing, probably easy for you guys :)

Comment: Don't use `$input` as self-defined variable name, because it is an [Automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7#input) in PowerShell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$INPUT` is an [automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-5.1#input):

> Contains an enumerator that enumerates all input that is passed to a
>   function. The $input variable is available only to functions and
>   script blocks (which are unnamed functions).

So just use another variable, e. g. `$user` instead of `$input`